# Best way to choose between member values in a function

Tags: c#

First off, I totally apologize for the title, I don't know what the heck to put, it's such a confusing concept to really explain in a title, so bear with me.

```
public class fido
{       
   public void foo(process proc)
   {
      if (/* comparing by time */)
      {
         if (proc[parent].time < proc[child].time)
         {
            //do something
         }
      }

      else if (/* comparing by priority */)
      {
         if (proc[parent].priority < proc[child].priority)
         {
            //do something
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How do I go about shortening this?  I was hoping it could be as simple as using a "defined" member through the parameter of foo().

For example

```
public class fido
{       
   public void foo(process proc, something mem)
   {
      if (/* comparing by time */)
      {
         if (proc[parent].mem < proc[child].mem)
         {
            //do something
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I would use something like

```
foo(processA, time); // If I want to use time member
foo(processB, priority); // Or if I want to use priority member
```

I know the previous codes are 100% incorrect, but I hope you understand what I'm getting at.

I'm just trying to shorten the code because what I have is a priority queue class that uses heap and everything to prioritize values, however I need to use the class for multiple types of values, such as time and priority.  I definitely do not want to create a duplicate class (totally not beneficial), I'm looking for a way I can shorten it.  Does anybody know the best way?

Comment: Sounds like you want to make your type generic and take in IEqualityComparer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an `enum` as a parameter in your method.

```
public class Fido
{

    public void foo(Process proc, Options options)
    {
        if (options == Options.Time)
        {
            //Do time work
        }

        else if (options == Options.Priority)
        {
            //Do priority work
        }
    }
}

public enum Options
{
    Time,
    Priority
}
```

Note that a passing a `bool` instead of an `enum` would work here as well. It just makes things a bit less readable.

Comment: Yeah, but what I was hoping to do was making it so it wouldn't have to make checks to confirm if it wants to compare by time or priority.

Comment: @user1880591, how do you plan on executing different code for each scenario then? You could overload `foo()` and execute the overloaded method depending on whether you want time/priority, but this is a far better solution in my opinion.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was anything out there, but your way of using enum is certainly better than what I currently have.  Thanks!